# Will a negative reward points balance of a credit card incur interest?

Tags: credit-card, reward-program

If I have a credit card with a negative reward points balance (say due to a returned product), and if I let the reward balance remain negative, will this eventually incur interest charges?

A negative reward points balance means I owe the credit card company some money. Thus I will not be surprised if they will charge interest on this amount. But I am not sure if they will send me a bill for this. Should I make some purchases with this card so that the reward balance becomes positive or zero, or it is okay to leave it negative?

Answer (score 1):

This may or my not be outlined in your cardholder agreement...

I am quite certain that they would NOT incur interest, since points in general are not "money", but a non-monetary benefit which *could* be redeemed for money.  I suspect that instead, you would just "pay back" the negative balance as you earn points with future purchases.

> A negative reward points balance means I owe the credit card company some money.

No, you don't "owe" the bank anything, just like they don't "owe" you anything when you earn points - it *can* be redeemed for cash or goods, but it's not a financial debt to them, and they can "reverse" points for a number of reasons (usually involving fraud or misuse).  A negative points balance would just a debit balance that will likely get "paid back" by future benefits that you would have earned.

> Should I make some purchases with this card so that the reward balance becomes positive or zero

No - just like you shouldn't make purchases just to earn points, you shouldn't make purchases just to erase the negative points balance. Let is correct itself naturally.

If you *want* to use it to spend on things that you would have bought anyway, that's fine, but I wouldn't go on a "shopping spree" just to get rid of the deficit, and I certainly wouldn't spend more than you could absolutely pay back without accruing any interest.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This happens to a card that I do not use often anyway. So in this sense, I can leave it negative forever without worrying about anything? After all, hypothetically, this amount I owe can be large if I have just returned an expensive product.

Comment: It's possible, but not something I would lose sleep over. If the points were originally redeemed for a statement credit they _might_ try to recover the "loss" at some point.

Comment: I am amazed they let you go negative in the first place.

Comment: @keshlam, redeem all points, then return a product.

Comment: Interesting. I redeem about once a quarter (as cash) and return products for refund almost never (except unused building supplies).

Comment: I have heard stories of abuse of promos ("Earn 50,000 points if you spend $3,000"). Where people buy a big ticket item and return it after the points are applied and spent. The bank then debits the points, creating a negative balance. So _abuse_ may trigger some monetary clawback, but legitimate negative balances probably wouldn't.